# Excel - add cell id to SUM() in another cell

Tags: excel

I have two columns of cells - **I4:I28** (these have currency data) and **G4:G28** (these are Yes/No dropdown lists). These two columns refer to each other: **G4 Yes/No > I4**, **G5 Yes/No > I5** and so on).

[image: Columns **G** and **I**]

Finally I have this cell - **C19** - where I **SUM** the **I4:I28** data: **=SUM(I4:I28)**

[image: **C19** cell - SUM() function]

I need the **SUM()** function in **C19** to include ONLY the **I** cells that have it's correspondent **G** column **Yes** selected. How do I make this kind of validation?

Thanx

P

P.S.: I suppose it would be something like this (pseudo code): If **G4="Yes"** Then Add **I4** to **SUM()** in **C19**...

Comment: You need `SUMIF`:http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SUMIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) *Syntax:`SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)`*

In Cell `C19`

`=SUMIF(G4:G28,"Yes",I4:I28)`

Comment: That window that says: "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert function..." "... Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: you type: =1+1, cel shows: 2; to get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: you type: '=1+1, cell shows: =1+1"

Comment: I think you are having issues with your localized version of Excel. Try this: `=SUMIF(G4:G28;"YES";I4:I28)` Bom Dia, pra voce!

Comment: It's the english version actually. :) Now the error is gone, but it doesn't make the sum - it gives me 0€.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a new column that would have the following code:

```
IF G4 == "YES" THEN G4 ELSE 0
```

And sum that column up with `SUM()`.

The other solution is to use `SUMIF`.

In your example it would be:

```
=SUMIF(G4:G28,"==YES",I4:I28)
```